# Reference request: rates of weak convergence of Polish space-valued random variables

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $(E,\mathscr{E})$ be a Polish space $E$ together with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{E}$. Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $(X^{(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $E$-valued random variables; i.e. for each $n$ we have $X^{(n)}:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\to(E,\mathscr{E})$. Suppose there is another $E$-valued random variable $X$ such that
$$\mathsf{E}[f(X^{(n)})]\to \mathsf{E}[f(X)],\,\forall f\in C_b(E)$$ Then we say that $X^{(n)}\stackrel{\textrm{w}}{\to}X$ or that we have weak convergence of the laws $\mathscr{L}^{(n)}:=P\circ (X^{(n)})^{-1}$ towards $\mathscr{L}:=P\circ X^{-1}$ in $\mathscr{P}(E)$, the Polish space of probability measures on $E$. The space $\mathscr{P}(E)$ is assumed to be equipped with the coarsest topology such that the maps $\mu\mapsto \int f d\mu$ are continuous for all bounded continuous functions $f$ on $E$.

In the context of convergence of stochastic processes, we work with the Skorokhod space $E=\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued càdlàg processes, equipped with the Skorokhod topology.

I am specifically looking for *books, papers and/or references* which present results on, and **with any interesting assumption needed for**:

- Bounds on the errors $\varepsilon_{(n)}:=|\mathsf{E}[f(X^{(n)})]- \mathsf{E}[f(X)]|$;
- 'Rates' of weak convergence (e.g. as functions of $n$);
- 'Distance' between $\mathscr{L}^{(n)}$ and $\mathscr{L}$, and how this may go to $0$;

et similia. The fact that I could not find anything about these in this (probabilistic) setting makes me suspect that these things have been studied in more general form in fields such as functional analysis.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Clearly, one cannot get any rates without specific assumptions on the $X^{(n)}$'s.

Comment: @IosifPinelis of course! I will clarify in an edit.

Comment: An area where distances between such laws have been extensively studied is optimal transport theory. If $d$ is a bounded metric that metrizes $E$. there is a metric $\rho$ on the probability measures given by $\rho(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\inf\int d~\mathrm d\mu$ with the infimum over all probability measures $\mu$ on $E\times E$ that have marginal $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively. There is a huge literature on such distances.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker yes, I am aware of that. However, I haven't found references in which, in addition, weak convergence is studied using these distances. If you have some, do comment or post :)

Comment: "Topics in Optimal Transportation" has a proof of the central limit theorem using transport methods if that counts.